# Confusing ping response

Tags: networking, routing, ping

I have a computer on the `192.168.10.x` subnet and am trying to ping a device on the `192.168.12.x` subnet. I can ping other devices on the `.12.x` successfully but when I try and ping `.12.167` I get the following response:

```
C:\windows\system32>ping nodexxxx

Pinging nodexxxx.xxxxxx.com [192.168.12.167] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.10.73: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.10.73: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.10.73: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.10.73: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.12.167:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
```

As I understand it, if the response is "Destination host unreachable" only, then there is an issue with the routing on the local machine but if the response is as above, with the IP address included, the issue lies with routing out on the network.

The confusing part is `192.168.10.73` is the address of my machine.

Can anyone figure this one out?

Comment: Are the netmask and the default gateway correctly set on the  `.12.167`device?

Comment: I have no idea, I cannot connect to them. They are not standard servers/switches/etc.

Comment: I cannot ping the gateway either (get "Request timed out") but I can connect to it in a browser session.

Comment: I have tried pinging the gateway from another machine but get the same problem.

Comment: You stated that you cannot ping the router from at least 2 different machines, is it possible that ICMP traffic is turned off on the router?
What happens when you run a tracert to the .12.167 device?

Comment: Guess: 192.168.10.73 is a router on the path to 192.168.12.167, which tries to forward the packet, but decides it can't, and sends back a packet "Destination host unreachable". Can you do a traceroute?